# FileOutputStream - sometime writing data and sometime not

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I am trying to understand few java file concepts. So I tried with below program to understand FileOutputStream

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
int i = 1;
out.write(i);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Some binary data has been writen in the file.

But the for the same program when I change the value of `i` from 1 to 10. I don't see anything in my output file. Can someone explain me why with some internal details.

Comment: What are you using to look at your output file?  Would it be a text editor that displays ASCII 10 as a newline, which you can't see?

Comment: I think you'll see the number if instead you use `PrintWriter` or `FileWriter`

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I used gedit and intellij idea to view my file. Even for other number like 9, 13, nothing I can able to view.

Comment: Is it showing 9 as a tab character and 13 as a carriage return perhaps?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes I hope so, I am referring to ASCII Codes Table now :)

Comment: So, there's nothing wrong with your Java code.

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong with the code, may be redundant flush is not needed

Comment: That's correct.  There's no point in doing both `flush` and `close`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i = 1;
out.write(i);
```

That writes `0x1` to the file.

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

The `flush()` is redundant.

> Some binary data has been writen in the file.

Correct.

> But the for the same program when I change the value of i from 1 to 10. I don't see anything in my output file.

Yes you do. You see `0xa`, which is a line feed character.

Comment: Still I dont see anything, may be because of the text-editor(gedit) I am using. Even for other number like 9, 13, nothing I can able to view.

Comment: 9 is a tab. 13 is a carriage return. These are not visible in text editors, any more than line feed is. 8 is BEL, 12 is form-feed: you won't see those either, or many others. Your expectations are awry. If you're writing binary you should be using a hex viewer.